# Помогите сделать разметку layout для фрагментов Android

Tags: android

Есть три фрагмента, выводятся в один layout, для вертикальной и горизонтальной ориентации разное расположение. Надо вот так (схема):

[image: Вертик. разметка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вертикальной ориентации в Фрагменте1 ставлю layout_weight="0.1"
для Фрагмента 2 и 3 layout_weight="0.5" и 0.4 соответственно.
Layout для фрагмента 1, остальные похожие.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/display_header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.1"
          android:orientation="vertical">
```

В активити:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_activity);

if (fragment == null) {
    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment3 fragment3 = new Fragment3();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_activity, fragment1);
    ft.add(R.id.main_activity, fragment2);
    ft.add(R.id.main_activity, fragment3);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Так не работает, для горизонтальной вообще не пойму как.

Comment: горизонтальная для планшетов предусмотрена или для любого устройства, просто при повороте будет меняться layout?

Comment: Горизонтальная для любого устройства, layout другой (land) .

Comment: разметку полностью приведите ...

Answer (score 0):

Можите сделать это в xml коде

Для layout в которому хотите отобразить фрагменты сделайте следующую разметку

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.viktor.fragment.Fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1">
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.viktor.fragment.Fragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.viktor.fragment.Fragment3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">
</fragment>
```

в поле android:name="" - указывайте layout которые используются для фрагментов

Comment: Надо именно програмно. Потом сюда будут выводиться другие фрагменты.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда сделайте xml код так:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conteiner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"></FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conteiner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"></FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conteiner3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

А java код:

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
Fragment3 fragment3 = new Fragment3();

FragmentTransaction fT = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fT.replace(R.id.conteiner1, fragment1);
fT.replace(R.id.conteiner2, fragment2);
fT.replace(R.id.conteiner3, fragment3);
fT.commit();
```